# Change font size of Subsection in the header in Beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, fontsize

I want to change the font size of Subsection appearing in the header area. The overall document size is set to 12pt, this is making the Subsection too big to fit in the header area. I want to set it to 9pt.
My MWE:

```
\documentclass[british,12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont}
%I tried this, but it's throwing an error, which reads:
%Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 34, which was the \tableofcontents command.

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Lecture Overview}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\section[Elaborate Title]{Title}
\subsection[Elaborate Text]{Title}
\begin{frame}
content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I tried the same with 9pt font size for the overall document everything works as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax for `\setbeamerfont` is:

```
\setbeamerfont{<some beamer element>}{size=<desired size>}
```

In your case

```
\setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{size=\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont}
```